# How to display Facebook Like button and Twitter Tweet button next to each other?

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, disqus

I cannot get the FB Like button and the Tweet button to display next to each other!!

HTML:

```
<div class="grid_3 social">
  <ul>
     <li>
          <fb:like href="http://{{ request.get_host }}{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url={{ "http://localhost:8000"|urlencode }}{{ post.get_absolute_url }}&text=mytext" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social {
float: right;
}
.social ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    display: inline;
}

.social li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I tried every combination I can think of to no avail. Help please!! CSS will be the death of me...

While we're on the subject of these buttons, we all know they double and triple your page's load time because they make a lot of JS calls, especially when you're on something like a blog index page. Anyone have any ideas on how to remedy this situation? I'm already using Disqus, and now adding FB and Twitter my index page can take up to 5 seconds to load. So slow. Would showing no counts on the buttons help?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Actual HTML taken from Firebug:

```
      <div class="grid_3 social">
<ul>
<li>
<fb:like class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" font="" width="450" show_faces="false" layout="button_count" href="http://localhost:8000/24/">
<span>
<iframe id="f3625cd56daea42" class="fb_ltr" scrolling="no" name="fdb43a564bf6bc" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 25px; width: 450px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=109222892497007&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D0%23cb%3Df30031a637a623%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8000%252Ff1d530a50043dd4%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&href=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F24%2F&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=450">
<html id="facebook" class=" " lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body class="plugin transparent_widget ff3 mac Locale_en_US">
<input id="post_form_id" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="fa23e0256eb11be4c423202178ac80f5" name="post_form_id">
<div id="FB_HiddenContainer" style="position:absolute; top:-10000px; width:0px; height:0px;"></div>
<div id="LikePluginPagelet">
<div id="connect_widget_4daeb2d755f689e27484431" class="connect_widget button_count" style="">
<table class="connect_widget_interactive_area">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="connect_widget_vertical_center connect_widget_button_cell">
<div class="connect_button_slider">
<div class="connect_button_container">
<a class="connect_widget_like_button clearfix like_button_no_like">
<div class="tombstone_cross"></div>
<span class="liketext">Like</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="connect_widget_vertical_center connect_widget_confirm_cell">
<td class="connect_widget_button_count_including hidden_elem">
<td class="connect_widget_button_count_excluding">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</span>
</fb:like>
</li>
<li>
<iframe class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-horizontal" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://platform0.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?_=1303294651733&count=horizontal&lang=en&text=mytext&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F24%2F" style="width: 110px; height: 20px;" title="Twitter For Websites: Tweet Button">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body class="hcount show-count">
</html>
</iframe>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
.social li {
    float: left;
}
```

It would help to see your actual HTML. `<fb:like>` is not an HTML tag, it’s Facebook’s little markup language they made up (FBML), and it gets replaced with actual HTML when Facebook’s JavaScript runs.

(I believe they’re looking to deprecate FBML too — you might want to have a look at the `<iframe>`-based like button.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my post with the generated HTML I copied from Firebug. Are they really gonna deprecate FBML? That's a little silly since the reason I chose the FBML over straight iframe is because they wrote "XFBML is more versatile." In any case, the XFBML generates iframe code anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @rabbid: You‘re most welcome. Yup, [they are](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/). It makes sense really: FBML was just a layer on top of HTML, and unless an extra layer is isolating a lot of complexity, it’s not worth having it. The web runs on HTML, so if you’re working on the web, you need to learn HTML.

Comment: @rabbid: hm, your HTML from Firebug is a little odd — where did the Tweet button go? And did my suggested CSS help your layout?

Comment: Oops sorry. It was in an <li> that I did not expand. I pasted the HTML again. And no unfortunately your CSS did not work. Any other ideas? Regarding FBML, so are you saying I should remove the FBML and just use the iframe code? If that helps with speed I'm all for it.

Comment: @rabbid: ah! Gotcha, cheers. That’s odd that floating didn’t put them side-by-side. I would note that Facebook’s iframe for their like button is 450px wide, and Twitter’s Tweet button iframe is 110px wide — how much width is available inside `<div class="social">`? If it’s less than 560px, you won’t be able to get the buttons side-by-side.

Comment: holy crap you're right! that must be it! why does it need to be 450px?? that's huge! my whole container is only 960px. Since that value is generated by FB's Javascript, how should I fix this? That iframe's style is written inline, so I can't override it with CSS.

Comment: ugh I'm such an idiot. I can set the width in the FBML code... Thanks a lot for your help Paul!

Comment: @rabbid: re the speed of FMBL vs iframes, I’ve no idea. I’d suggest moving away from FBML because Facebook are deprecating it — when the people who invented something don’t support it any more, it’s got to be pretty amazing to be worth sticking with.

Comment: @rabbid: heh! Aw, it’s easy to miss what the actual problem is when there’s so much going on. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, you would want to load the javascript asynchronously - someone has modified the twitter script to do so, and I would imagine the facebook script has been modified to do the same.

I can't find links too readily on google, but for 5 seconds a page I'm sure you have the motivation!

Comment: I am in fact using the async way to load Facebook using code that FB themselves provided. I guess my words are inaccurate. My page (mostly) loads within 1 second or so. But these damn buttons take 3-4 seconds to load. It's very annoying to see. I can't imagine how TechCrunch handles it. They implement every button available in the universe on their posts. I'll go search for the async Twitter code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I have found is to wrap your buttons in a LI inside a UL.

Take your facebook button code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

Change the DIV tag to LI, and set it inside the UL with the rest of your buttons:

```
<li class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></li>
```

And set your CSS widths for the class fb-like down to something closer to its actual size.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign following `CSS Class` to your List Items

```
.NextTo
{
    float : left;
}
```

or

```
.NextTo
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also spent a lot of time to bring them together and show next to each other and finally found the easiest solution..

You simply need to past html codes between:

```
<div align="center">... past your code here...`</div>`
```

Comment: align="center" is not valid HTML and was deprecated as far back as HTML 4.01